# filtering a text file with a certain string in a line then returning another string within the line

Tags: json, string, python-2.7, filter

this is my text file named team.json
my problem is that I only know how to return a specific line,
For example i select a filter location, like PQ how would i return the names that has a PQ location. thanks in advance.

```
{
  "members": [
    {"name": "John", "location": "QC", "age": 25},
    {"name": "Jesse", "location": "PQ", "age": 24},
    {"name": "Jez", "location": "PQ", "age": 23},
    {"name": "Ry", "location": "PQ", "age": 22},
    {"name": "Barry", "location": "PQ", "age": 25},
    {"name": "Rikki", "location": "PQ", "age": 35},
    {"name": "Ross", "location": "PQ", "age": 33},
    {"name": "Chiz", "location": "PQ", "age": 25},
    {"name": "Gel", "location": "PQ", "age": 24},
    {"name": "Cherry", "location": "PQ", "age": 22}
  ]
}
```

this is my code but only returns the line

```
import json
my_data = json.loads(open("team.json.txt").read())

print my_data

for line in open('team.json.txt'):
 if "John" in line:
  print line
```

Comment: Use your my_data object to find the data you are looking for instead of string comparison in line

Comment: hello sir.. thanks for answering maybe i should look up the function my_data object if im right is it a function?.. Im a newbie and trying to learn python..

Comment: Please see exactly what @hiro protagonist describes in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have parsed your json data you could use this to extract members in the PQ location:

```
member_in_pq = [member for member in my_data['members'] \
    if member['location'] == 'PQ']
print(member_in_pq)
# -> [{'age': 24, 'location': 'PQ', 'name': 'Jesse'}, ...]
```

or, if you want just the names:

```
member_in_pq = [member['name'] for member in my_data['members'] \
    if member['location'] == 'PQ']
print(member_in_pq)
# -> ['Jesse', 'Jez',..., 'Cherry']
```

i recommend using the parsed version of your data instead of going back and parsing the file (again) manually.