# getting the value from text file after the colon or before the colon in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I only need the last number 25 so i can change it to int().  I have this text file:

```
{
  "members": [
    {"name": "John", "location": "QC", "age": 25},
    {"name": "Jesse", "location": "PQ", "age": 24},
}
```

then return the value of the age

This what I have tried so far, so I am so stuck...  What kind of function do I use to parse it?  Is that what you call it?  I'm new to programming and in python.

```
import json
import pprint

my_data = json.loads(open("team.json.txt").read())

print 'members whose location is in PQ'
member_in_pq = [member for member in my_data['members'] \
    if member['location'] == 'PQ']
pprint.pprint(member_in_pq)
```

By the way I tried this code but it gives an error:

```
result = my_data.split(':')[-1]
```

Comment: Do you want `member_in_pq = [member["age"] for member in my_data['members'] \
    if member['location'] == 'PQ']`?

Comment: i want to use my_data is it posible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [filtering a text file with a certain string in a line then returning another string within the line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174716/filtering-a-text-file-with-a-certain-string-in-a-line-then-returning-another-str)

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I dont understand.. can u pls give me a sample code ty

Comment: did you try [muddyfish](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3398583/muddyfish)'s approach? that's it.

Comment: i got this result from @muddyfish [25,24] i only need 25.. so ill just remove ther for loop?

Comment: or i could get 24 its just so that ican extract it from my text file then convert it too int so i can do a filtering

Comment: Then you have more data then you posted, (Your JSON is invalid as well), change ` == 'PQ']` to ` == 'QC']`

Comment: I got it @muddyfish thanks so the brackets wont botherme if i change it to int? by the way sorry about putting more data.. and about the JSON how is it invalid.

Comment: Try running it through jsonlint. And the brackets will matter, to get rid of them add `[0]` to the end of the other I gave you. Note that if there is another element with location QC, then it will output the first age rather than all of them.

Comment: your json is missing a closing `]`.

Comment: YEP thanks for that @hiroprotagonist..  if i have a data or text file which has more than QC it returns all the ages with qc but i only need one age per line thanks again

Comment: @muddyfish what wud u suggest i do to get the second third or fourth age? thanks

Comment: Use a `for` loop to iterate over the list produced

Comment: ok2 tnx.. i've got an idea on how to filter it.. big help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking how to do, but will make an attempt to guess.

First of all, the text you show isn't valid JSON and would need to be changed to something like this:

```
{                                                  
  "members": [                                     
    {"name": "John", "location": "QC", "age": 25}, 
    {"name": "Jesse", "location": "PQ", "age": 24}
  ]
}
```

Here's something that would print out all the data for each member in location `PQ`:

```
import json
import pprint

my_data = json.loads(open("team.json.txt").read())

members_in_pq = [member for member in my_data['members']
                    if member['location'] == 'PQ']

print 'members whose location is in PQ'
for member in members_in_pq:
    print '  name: {name}, location: {location}, age: {age}'.format(**member)
```

Output:

```
members whose location is in PQ
  name: Jesse, location: PQ, age: 24
```

Comment: also a big help understanding python though i only need the 25 or 24 either one so i could change it to int because i need to filter by age range with this whole text which has more than two names in it

Comment: there are more than two names but i apasted only two just put two

Comment: The `**member` unpacks all the entries in the dictionary and turns them into keyword arguments. For example for the `member` data dictionary shown, it turned it into `.format(name='Jesse', location='PQ', age=24)`. This was needed to make it work with the preceding formatting string which referenced the arguments with those names.

Comment: BTW, to directly reference the age value of the second member of the 'members' list in `my_data` would be: `my_data['members'][1]['age']`.