# Filtering in python most efficient way from a list is it using while or do or for or other function

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter

The following is my file and code.

I'm quite stuck as to what I'm supposed to do and can't formulate a filtering program that would output names of people who I want to filter out.  Sample is `PQ` and `age` 24 to 25: output should be `Jesse, Barry, Gel`.

```
   {
      "members": [
        {"name": "John", "location": "QC", "age": 25},
        {"name": "Jesse", "location": "PQ", "age": 24},
        {"name": "Jez", "location": "PQ", "age": 23},
        {"name": "Ry", "location": "PQ", "age": 22},
        {"name": "Barry", "location": "PQ", "age": 25},
        {"name": "Rikki", "location": "PQ", "age": 35},
        {"name": "Ross", "location": "PQ", "age": 33},
        {"name": "Chiz", "location": "PQ", "age": 25},
        {"name": "Gel", "location": "PQ", "age": 24},
        {"name": "Cherry", "location": "PQ", "age": 22}
      ]
    }   


import json
import pprint

my_data = json.loads(open("team.json.txt").read())

print "Choose the lowest age limit:",
lower_age = raw_input()
print "Choose the highest age limit:",
higher_age = raw_input()

print "Members age from %r to %r." % ( lower_age, higher_age)

if lower_age == '22' and higher_age== '24':
    print 'hi'

age_22 = [member for member in my_data['members']
                if member['age'] == 22]
for member in age_22:
        print '{name}'.format(**member)
```

Comment: Are you the same person as @lrsantos17 who asked a simular question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178337/getting-the-value-from-text-file-after-the-colon-or-before-the-colon-in-python?noredirect=1#comment52244440_32178337) earlier?

Comment: I guess they both are pursuing same course, and it is the assignment.

Comment: i'm a friend of @lrsantos17.

Comment: See my comments on that question as well as the answer :)

Comment: @muddyfish i was told by another friend that i can use filter. which is easier filter or for loop?

Comment: A for loop almost certainly.